Angular 16.2 safari browser is not working
I am using angular 16.2.0 after build live site is working properly all browser except safari browser.
Am getting error on polyfills js file
class L{static{this.__symbol__=a}
this line am getting error after a curly bracket is error id its semicolon its working proper like this
class L{static#e=this.__symbol__=a;
How to fix this error.
Please look at the attachment

This is my package.json
    {
  "name": "invest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "clevertap-web-sdk": "^1.10.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^18.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.3.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "ua-parser-js": "^1.0.39",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/clevertap-web-sdk": "^1.1.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "@types/ua-parser-js": "^0.7.39",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}


Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

The lack of proper code formatting makes it difficult for readers to help you. Please [edit] your question to format inline code properly and to use a [code block] for any code or error messages you have included.
